# Getting hazard ratios from a univariate logistic regression model

Tags: logistic, hazard

The authors in the article mention that,

> *The subgroup analysis was conducted using a univariate logistic regression
> model, fitting separate models for each subgroup to assess the
> association between the primary outcome and a single variable.*

In the Figure 3 below are the results of the subgroup analysis :

[image]

I suppose HR means *hazard ratio*. I don't understand how they obtained HRs from a univariate logistic regression model.

Reference:

Culprit Lesion Coronary Intervention Before Complete Angiography in ST-Elevation Myocardial Infarction: A Randomized Clinical Trial, Nir Levi et al., JAMA Netw Open. 2024